# What is the word for "the study of the afterlife"?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Thanatology* is the scientific study of death, but is there a better term for the study of the afterlife?

Comment: ***Mythology***

Answer (score 2):

It is called **Eschatology**. Eschatology is the study of the afterlife.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eschatology) define it as:

> The part of theology concerned with death, judgement, and the **final destiny of the soul** and of humankind.

Citation from the book: [The Ethical Foundations of Criminal Justice](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=MOwtajg4OD4C&pg=PA15&dq=the+study+of+the+afterlife+is+called+Eschatology&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg_-7f6pjdAhUMXisKHV4PA8wQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Eschatology&f=false)  By Richard A. Spurgeon Hall, Carolyn Brown

> The systematic study of the afterlife is called Eschatology